# Is there a way to get rid of > Warning: [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.jacoco.excludes" was provided; it will be ignored

Tags: maven, configuration, quarkus, jacoco

Using Quarkus 2.14.2.Final, with `quarkus-maven-plugin` and `quarkus-jacoco`.

pom.xml:

```xml
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

In application.yml containing:

```yaml
quarkus:
  jacoco:
    excludes:
      - "**/dto/*"
      - "**/domain/*"
```

as described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/tests-with-coverage#quarkus-jacoco-jacoco-config_quarkus.jacoco.excludes)

When I run `mvn package`, I get this warning:

- [INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.14.2.Final:build (default) @ starling-round-up ---
- [WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.jacoco.excludes" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo

I'm not sure why I get this warning and how to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

Just for testing, can you try adding this configuration in the pom:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/dto/*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/domain/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
     </configuration>
     ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works !!
So this seems to be a false warning coming from the extension.
I used the base configuration coming from [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/tests-with-coverage#setting-up-jacoco) and configured as per your answer.